# TFS Get both XAML and VNEXT build definitions

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to get both xaml and vnext build definitions from my TFS using BuildHttpClient.GetDefinitionsAsync function but it brings me only vnext build definitions. Does it is a proper behavior of this function? It seems that it need to return both kind of build definitions.

I see that the underlying GET request contains type=Build parameter. According to [reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions) it is an optional parameter, but GetDefinitionsAsync has no such parameter in its signature...

**UPD**

I've tried is with the latest version (15.112.1) of Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)

The previous version ([14.102.0]) of the same package works well. The underlying GET request has no type parameter and brings both types of build definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **XamlBuildHttpClient** object in **Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client 15.0** package, which is used for XAML build, for example:

```
var buildClient = connection.GetClient<XamlBuildHttpClient>();
var defs = buildClient.GetDefinitionsAsync(project: "XXX").Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue at my side, I also tried **Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client**  (version 15.112.1), it has the same issue.

The previous version ([14.102.0]) works.

I have submitted a [feedback here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/82465/tfs-can-not-get-the-xaml-build-definitions-when-us.html) for this issue, you can track it as needed.

In the other hand, you can also use the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-list-of-build-definitions) (api-version = 2.0) to get both XAML and VNEXT build definitions, eg:

```
GET http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC/TFVC-Scrum/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0
```